# Access OpenTSDB data through Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, opentsdb

I currently have a HBase database on which is running an OpenTSDB instance. The OpenTSDB data needs to be processed in a distributed manner.

I actually know that OpenTSDB stores the collected metrics and values on HBase. However, it is stored as BLOB format (Binary large object), which makes it difficult to leverage engines like Pig or Hive for data processing since data os not stored in a common way.

I've done lots of research and I actually found 3 things :

1. R2Time project which is able to read data directly from OpenTSDB and perform distributed MapReduce algorithms
2. A connector OpenTSDB <-> Spark https://github.com/achak1987/opentsdb-spark
3. I also heard of tackling HBase HTTP API to use data

Since the 2 first options did not work for me, I really need another alternative involving any data processing engine (Spark or other) to have my work done.

I'd be very grateful if someone has any hacks to get out of this locked way.

Thanks